# Implementing the Room Database (Android)

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-room, android-livedata

I like to know how to properly integrate the Room Library within an Android Application. Some articles I have seen uses a Singleton approach using a Respository for database calls, while other uses some form of Dependecy Injection (Dagger 2). I like to know the proper integration of this library?

Thanks

Comment: What about consulting the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best place is codelabs, it has a [simple](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-persistence/#0) implementation, as well as a more [complex](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/build-app-with-arch-components/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0) one. All using Room.

Edit: Above links seems to be removed. Here are a couple of resources to replace that:

1. [Android room with a view](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin#0)
2. [Room + LiveData + ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-training-livedata-viewmodel?index=..%2F..%2Fandroid-training&hl=th#0)

Comment: the links in this response not working today

Answer (score 2):

**ROOM Database**

- Room is an ORM (Object Relational Mapper) for SQLite database in Android developement and part of Android Jetpack.
- Provides an abstraction layer over SQLite database
- Amount of boilerplate code is reduced
- Compile-time verification of SQL queries

**ROOM Database components**

- It has 3 main components Entity, Database, DAO.
- **Entity** is data class annotated with @Entity is like creating a table in SQLite and the variables in the model class are like columns in the table.
- **Database** is an abstract class which extends RoomDatabase and has list of entities associated with the database.
- **DAO(Data Access Object)** is an interface which defines the operations to be performed in our database.

**ROOM Database Implementation**

- Step 1 creating **Entity** data class

  @Entity(tableName = "yourOwnTableName")

  data class LocalData(

  ```
    val column1: String?,

    val column2: String?,  

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val product_local_id: Int?= null
  ```

  )
- Step 2 creating **Database**

  @Database(entities = [LocalData::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
  @TypeConverters

  abstract class LocalDB : RoomDatabase() {

  ```
    abstract fun localDataDao() : LocalDataDAO

    companion object{

        private var instance : LocalDB ? = null

        fun getInstance(context: Context) : LocalDB ?{
            if(instance == null){
                synchronized(LocalDB ::class){
                    instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext, LocalDB::class.java, "localBD.db").allowMainThreadQueries().build()
                }
            }
            return instance
        }

        fun destroyInstance(){
            instance = null
        }
    }
  ```

  }
- Step 3 creating **DAO**

  @Dao
  interface LocalDAO {

  ```
    @Insert
    fun insertData(productEntity: LocalData) : Long

    @Delete
    fun deleteData(productEntity: LocalData) : Int

    @Query("Select * from yourOwnTableName")
    fun showAllProducts(): List<LocalData>

    @Query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourOwnTableName")
    fun totalProducts(): Long
  ```

  }
- Step 4 is optional is creating **repository**

class ProductRepository(context: Context) {

```
var dbms : LocalDAO = LocalDB.getInstance(context)?.localDataDao()!!

fun insertData(productEntity: LocalData) : Long{
    return dbms.insertData(productEntity)
}

fun deleteData(productEntity: LocalData) : Int{
    return dbms.deleteData(productEntity)
}

fun getAllData() : List<LocalData> {
    return dbms.showAllProducts()
}

fun checkProductExist(id : Int) : Boolean{
    return dbms.exists(id)
}

fun totalProductsInCart() : Long{
    return dbms.totalProducts()
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your project needs, currently the most projects uses dependency injection. The reason you see many examples using a singleton, is because the autor intends not making the explanation of a new topic more complex.
You can see a [medium](https://medium.com/@alexis.tamher/getting-started-with-jetpack-room-9a0123b7bc24) that I wrote, and I did the same for the same reason.

Hope it be helpful.