# How can I save user input on their device using Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, saving-data

I have an app that records user inputs in EditTexts and then displays them in the second activity as a textView. However every time I close the app, those text fields reset. How could I save user input so that it will stay, even when the app is closed? Also, is there a way to reset the app with empty EditTexts every 24 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Option 1: You can use SharedPreferences or DataStore
- Option 2: Use local databases like SQLite (you can use Room)

Answer (score 1):

Use SharedPreferences or Preferences DataStore to persist data even after closing the app.

Answer (score 0):

As the others said you can use SharedPreferences or Room.

Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49799757/implementing-the-room-database-android) for Room Database or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-for-creating-one-time-activity-example) for SharedPreferences

Alternatively a guide to Room Database from an official source: [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room)